# Adding MapLibre to a new Android project is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, maplibre-gl

I am following the documentation to add the MapLiber library to a new Android project
https://maplibre.org/maplibre-native/docs/book/android/getting-started-guide.html

The Gradle sync seems to be working ok, but I get this error when trying to import the package

```
import org.maplibre.android.Maplibre
```

> Unresolved reference: maplibre

this is how I added the dependency

```
implementation 'org.maplibre.gl:android-sdk:10.0.2'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with the documentation. You can init like that:

```
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;

       Mapbox.getInstance(this);
```

[image]